# Azure Functions DefineSourceControl

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-sdk

I am attempting to automatically deploy and create an Azure Function App using the azure sdk.  I have reached the point where I need to link it to source control.  The available options are as follows from this sample [azure-libraries-for-net/Samples/AppService/ManageFunctionAppSourceControl.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/Samples/AppService/ManageFunctionAppSourceControl.cs):

Azure App Service basic sample for managing function apps.

- Create 5 function apps under the same new app service plan:

  - Deploy to 1 using FTP
  - Deploy to 2 using local Git repository
  - Deploy to 3 using a publicly available Git repository
  - Deploy to 4 using a GitHub repository with continuous integration
  - Deploy to 5 using web deploy

All my code is stored in Visual Studio Team Services.

Thanks in advance.

Is there anyway to link to Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: What's the result if you include the credential in the url? `https://test:{personal access token}@{account}.visualstudio.com/xxxxx`

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, it gives me an error message saying "An Error has occurred"

Answer (score 0):

Yes under Platform Features for your Functions App you can click Deployment Options and then select VSTS.  This is for more of a CI configuration.

If you want a more CD/Release Management style configuration that can also be done but you will configure that in VSTS in the Release definition/pipeline.

Comment: I am trying to link it using the azure sdk, when creating the function using code, I would like to link it to the source control repo.  According to the link above it can be done using github, I want to know if it's possible using vsts.